# filtering dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let say I have a dataframe created from a text file using case class schema. Below is the data stored in dataframe.

id -    Type- qt   -     P

1,  X,  10,     100.0

2,  Y,  20,     200.0

1,  Y,  15,     150.0

1,  X,  5,      120.0

I need to filter dataframe  by "id" and Type. And for every "id" iterate through the dataframe for some calculation. 
I tried this way but it did not work. Code snapshot.

```
     case class MyClass(id: Int, type: String, qt: Long, PRICE: Double)
     val df = sc.textFile("xyz.txt")
    .map(_.split(","))
    .map(p => MyClass(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1), p(2).trim.toLong, p(3).trim.toDouble)
    .toDF().cache()

    val productList: List[Int] = df.map{row => row.getInt(0)}.distinct.collect.toList
    val xList: List[RDD[MyClass]] = productList.map { 
            productId => df.filter({ item: MyClass => (item.id== productId) && (item.type == "X" })}.toList
    val yList: List[RDD[MyClass]] = productList.map { 
            productId => df.filter({ item: MyClass => (item.id== productId) && (item.type == "Y" })}.toList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the distinct idea from your example, simply iterate over all the IDs and filter the DataFrame according to the current ID. After this you have a DataFrame with only the relevant data:

```
val df3 = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/importantStuff.txt") //Your data here
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map(p => MyClass(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1), p(2).trim.toLong, p(3).trim.toDouble)).toDF().cache()

val productList: List[Int] = df3.map{row => row.getInt(0)}.distinct.collect.toList

println(productList)

productList.foreach(id => {
  val sqlDF = df3.filter(df3("id") === id)
  sqlDF.show()
})
```

sqlDF in the loop is the DF with the relevant data, later you can run your calculations on it.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.
I need one more help as below mentioned:
sqlDF.foreach(row => {caluculation(row); row.getLong(2) = row.getLong(2) - x })
so here for after every row caluculation , I need to upadte only row.getLong(2)[Single value not the entire column] and keeping rest dataframe as it is. 
 Could you please suggest how to do this?

Comment: @Advika I suggest you open a new thread asking this question. First it will allow to read it better and it will expose it to more people. Also since the answer solved the issue please mark it as answered.